# Angular 2 reactive forms with async validator trying to add ngClass if validation fails

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I have a HTML reactive form with async validation. When validation fails I tried to use `[class.has-errors]="hasErrors"` to add the CSS class has-errors into the  but it doesnt work.

```
   <form [formGroup]="myForm">
            <input type="text" formControlName="name">
            <input type="email" formControlName="email" [class.has-errors]="hasErrors">

            <div *ngIf="myForm.get('email').status === 'PENDING'">
                Checking...
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="myForm.get('email').status === 'VALID'">
                 Email is available!
            </div>

            <div *ngIf="myForm.get('email').errors && myForm.get('email').errors.emailTaken">
                 Oh noes, this email is already taken!
            </div>
        </form>
```

I have an async function

```
validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl) {
    return this.signupService.checkEmailNotTaken(control.value).map(res => {
        console.dir(res);
        this.hasErrors = !res;
        console.log('this.hasErrors=', this.hasErrors);
        return res ? null : { emailTaken: true };
    });
}
```

and i declared my formbuilder and forms this way

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        email: [
            '',
            [Validators.required, Validators.email],
            this.validateEmailNotTaken.bind(this)
        ]
    });
}
```

How should I add a class to my input box when my async fails?

Answer (score -1):

Catch the error as follows

```
 validateEmailNotTaken(control: AbstractControl) {
        return this.signupService.checkEmailNotTaken(control.value).map(res => {
            console.dir(res);
            this.hasErrors = !res;
            console.log('this.hasErrors=', this.hasErrors);
            return res ? null : { emailTaken: true };
        }).catch(error => {
           return Observable.throw(null);
        });
    }
```

To add 'has-errors' class when the async email validation fails

```
<input type="email" formControlName="email" [class.has-errors]="myForm.get('email').errors && myForm.get('email').errors.emailTaken">
```

To add 'has-errors' class when any validation fails,

```
<input type="email" formControlName="email" [class.has-errors]="myForm.get('email').errors">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. The DOM added has-errors class to the input box but the "Focus" css class is still in effect. So the input box will not appear to be in red in color from has-error class. How can I workaround with this?

Comment: It doesn't work. the catch part will not validate the field with throwing null